# PHP simplify if else statements

Tags: php, logic

I have the below code which does something if two values are true, something else if one of the two is true, something else if the other is true and something else if neither are true.
However I feel like there must be any easier way.

```
$value1 = true;
$value2 = false;

if ($value1 && $value2){
    do something
} else if ($value1){
    do something else
} else if ($value2){
    do another something
} else {
    do final other thing
}
```

Is there any way this logic can be represented in a better way with less if/else statements

Comment: No, there is no better way, since you're using 2 variables.

Comment: It is already simplified. Noway to further simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do inline condition which looks like this:

```
$value1 = true;
$value2 = false;

($value1 && value2)? do 1 : ($value)? do 2 : ($value2)?  do 3 : do 4;
```

It's not better way but it's still another way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
$a = true;
$b = false;

$ab = (int) $a . (int) $b;
switch($ab){
    case '00': echo '1'; break;
    case '01': echo '2'; break;
    case '10': echo '3'; break;
    case '11': echo '4'; break;
}
```

Not better but sometimes easier to read.